# Get telerik grid datasource after sorting

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik Gridview control I do drag and drop of rows correctly as described [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx)

And I created sorting as described [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/sorting/defaultcs.aspx)

But after sorting, I can't drag and drop rows, drag and drop stop working completely;
I need to get the datasource of the Telerik grid view and rebind it again after sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tap into the `NeedDataSource` event of the RadGrid.  This event fires everytime the grid needs data, so you don't have to worry about when to bind data.

[Check out this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/needdatasource/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Brian, i am already doing that i am binding the grid in NeedDataSource event but the problem that i uses a session to hold the data in drag and drop event so i need to refill that session with the new sorted data after sorting